# PostgreSQL 8.4 XML, XSLT and XPath possibilities / documentation

Tags: xml, postgresql, xpath, xslt

The available PostgreSQL material on XML, XSLT and XPath is limited. There are the official docs from the PostgreSQL team, however these cover only a few pages of content and I've never been convinced that their docs are as comprehensive as they could be.

There are also some bits and bobs on sites kicking around, however there is not too much.

Can anyone give me any examples of how they use the the XML functionality in PostgreSQL 8.4, or point at any hidden gem blog posts etc?

I'm especially interested in the xpath() and  xslt_process() functions.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Two (translated) articles:

- [XML, XSLT and PostgreSQL](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=nl&sl=nl&tl=en&u=http://www.yapf.net/index.php/XML,_XSLT_en_PostgreSQL&rurl=translate.google.nl&usg=ALkJrhgsMxP2-9ppsm_LWW1z8ZSvu5mcog)
- [PostgreSQL and xslt](http://translate.googleusercontent.com/translate_c?hl=nl&sl=nl&tl=en&u=http://www.yapf.net/index.php/PostgreSQL_en_xslt&rurl=translate.google.nl&usg=ALkJrhhrXGVTwaYH62ZoxtnmgbMB1xNg0Q)